# Vaadin Grid wrap labels in componentColumns

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm currently working on a webapp project in Vaadin 10. On the main page there's an overview of your current chats. Each chat is displayed as a bubble looking like:

[image]

It contains an image and a label.

I placed the bubbles in a Grid to ensure fast loading and flexibility like this:

```
`Grid<VisualGroup> cloudGrid = new Grid<VisualGroup>();
cloudGrid.setWidth("100%");
cloudGrid.setHeight("100%");
cloudGrid.getElement().getStyle().set("border","white");
cloudGrid.addComponentColumn(VisualGroupComponent::new);
cloudGrid.setItems(groups);`
```

My problem is that the label does not wrap when I put the components in the grid. If I create the component independently the text wraps correctly like:

[image]

But if I use the grid like described above it looks:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get text wrapping working in `ComponentColumns` in Vaadin?

If anyone knows the exact attribute I need to overwrite to get just the wrapping working and not delete every thing else that would probably the best solution. But for now that is a workaround.

Comment: Using Label is not adviced to be used with ComponentColumns (more info is found here: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4394, and her https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/3532, which warns possible issues regarding accessibility). There is also discussion about re-naming of the component (see: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4384)

Comment: @TatuLund Thanks. I did not know that you are not supposed to use Labels in that way. What Component should I correctly use instead for displaying text in a custom component that needs to go into a grid view?

Comment: One alternative would be to compose them in Div.

Comment: You mean something like `Div name = new Div(); name.setText(group.getName());`? I've got the same wrapping problem there. When creating the Component directly the text wraps correctly, but it doesn't wrap at all when placed inside a Grid.

Comment: Then it sounds like a possible bug, although final conclusion would require seeing your full code. I would create issue about this in https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues and add reproducing sample code to ticket.